# ngTouch ngClick doesn't bubble

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From the [ngTouch ngClick documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick):

> A more powerful replacement for the default ngClick designed to be used on touchscreen devices. Most mobile browsers wait about 300ms after a tap-and-release before sending the click event. This version handles them immediately, and then prevents the following click event from propagating.

This creates inconsistent behavior in that on a computer, the click event continues to bubble/propagate, but on mobile, it stops. This means that any directives higher in the dom that listen for element clicks fail. Seems like a bug to me, but I must not be the first person to have to work around this.

If you look at the [ngTouch code, the problem stems from line 453](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngTouch/directive/ngClick.js#L260)

```
element.triggerHandler('click', [event]);
```

[Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> `angular.element` delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."

jqLite has access to jQuery's `triggerHandler`, but not `trigger`.

[jQuery docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> The .triggerHandler() method behaves similarly to .trigger(), with the following exceptions:
>
> - Events triggered with .triggerHandler() do not bubble up the DOM hierarchy; if they are not handled by the target element directly, they do nothing.

So the Angular folks need to add `trigger` support to jqLite and change that line to `trigger` for it to work properly.

In the meantime, how can I work around this? Is there a way to use ngClick inside of a custom directive?

---

Bonus for laughs: [Comment from the ngTouch source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngTouch/directive/ngClick.js#L62-L99)

```
// This is an ugly, terrible hack!
// Yeah, tell me about it.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've replaced line 453 with

```
element[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', event));
```

It's working as expected for now. Not sure what browser compatibility is like for `new MouseEvent()`, so feel free to comment if you are.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to the above solution, i also had to add ng-click="" to each of my anchors to make this work.

note: i would have preferred to write this as a comment but stackoverflow doesn't feel i have earned the right. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of ngTouch 1.5.3+ should no longer have this problem. See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/0dfc1dfebf26af7f951f301c4e3848ac46f05d7f

It was a byproduct of ngTocuh code meant to overcome the 300ms mobile browser delay problem. See http://developer.telerik.com/featured/300-ms-click-delay-ios-8/ for more on that.